# Booty Bay from World of Warcraft

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, design

I would like to build a replica of Booty Bay from World of Warcraft.
Here's some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

To make the ramps angled correctly, I'm planning on using something like [part # 44570](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44570&name=Hinge%20Plate%203%20x%204%20Locking%20Dual%202%20Finger&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:%2285%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image]

Can you help me find the other side of this hinge?

How do I get the platforms to curve around in in a circle to replicate the bay?

I'm considering using brown Technic axles and twine to achieve the 'rugged jungle' look. Is that a good idea? Is there a way to get Technic axles shifted to a 30 degree or 45 degree angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technic has plenty of angled connectors named #1 to #6. Below is a #4 - part 42156.
[image]

However, it may be easier to use part 53585, which is an angled ball joint, in tandem with 32174, a ball socket. This allows you to create any angle you want, but those angles won't be permanently sturdy.

[image] [image]

For creating a curved dock, you can use hinge pieces like 2429/2430, or you can connect plates with only 1 stud between them and use that as a hinge.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Those angle connectors look useful. Is there way to connect a traditional 1 x 1 round brick to one of them?

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> *"To make the ramps angled correctly, I'm planning on using something*
>   *like [Part #44570](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44570&name=Hinge%20Plate%203%20x%204%20Locking%20Dual%202%20Finger&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:%2285%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*
>
> *Can you help me find the other side of this hinge?"*

- [*Part #44568 - White Hinge Plate 1 x 4 Locking Dual 1 Fingers on

  Side .*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44568&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

  [image]

Or maybe this x 2.

- *[White Hinge Plate 2 x 2 Locking with 1 Finger on Top.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92582&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)*

  [image]